# Creating a large GeoTIFF from multiple rasters

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcgis-10.3, geotiff-tiff

I have 1 million hectares of area and 1m raster data in ~200 tiles covering it. I am looking to reclassify the raster data and then create one image of the data in GeoTIFF format.

How can I accomplish this?

I am hoping that with the small raster cell size that the TIFF will still be producible and later usable.

Comment: Create a mosaic dataset, it's usable as a single raster without being a single raster. If you *really* need a single raster use *raster to other format* in catalog to export to a single GeoTIFF. @Luke, these tools are available in Standard and Advanced. http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00170000008n000000 http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Add_Rasters_To_Mosaic_Dataset/001700000085000000/ provided there is no overlap or colour balancing it's a fairly straightforward process.

Comment: I wasn't trying to lead the conversation to mosaic as it is a very large area and very small cell size and I have been having problems mosaicing rasters together to a GRID format so I didn't want to go down this route. I have yet to try mosaicing to TIFF as I thought it would be the same problem. So the only answer then is to use the mosaic tool?